# How to make the sidebar wider in docsify?

Tags: css, docsify

I have tried the following in  section of index.html and it does nothing:

```
  <style>
  :root {
    --sidebar-width : 100rem;
  }
  </style>
```

This is with a vanilla usage of docsify.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<style>` part and add your code to the `theme.css`

```
:root {
    --sidebar-width : 100rem;
  }
```